WFS server not showing any data (it previously did) I can still connect but none of the layers display
I am having trouble with our state WFS Server. The server address is
https://services.thelist.tas.gov.au/arcgis/services/Public/OpenDataWFS/MapServer/WFSServer
I used to be able to connect to it and display layers, but I have been away on leave for a year and something has changed either on the server side or the QGIS side. At the time I was using 3.22.1
I can connect to the server, load the layers, add a layer but can't get any data to show. I have tried different layers, a new project, defaulting my coordinate system to EPSG:3857 and all the other different check options. Could someone tell me why these are not showing anything?
The Cadastral Parcels layer for example will have plenty of data over any populated area.
This was my source from a QGIS 3.22.1 project that worked at the time
InvertAxisOrientation='1' pagingEnabled='true' preferCoordinatesForWfsT11='false' restrictToRequestBBOX='1' srsname='EPSG:3857' typename='Public_OpenDataWFS:LIST_Cadastral_Parcels' url='https://services.thelist.tas.gov.au/arcgis/services/Public/OpenDataWFS/MapServer/WFSServer' version='auto'

I am now using 3.34 and tried 3.36.3
If I open that 3.22.1 project it doesn't display any data for that layer but is not showing a repair data source either (so I figure it is still connecting to that server but not displaying anything for a reason?)
If I add that same layer into a new project in 3.36 with the WFS connection i get the following source
maxNumFeatures='2000' pageSize='2000' pagingEnabled='enabled' preferCoordinatesForWfsT11='false' restrictToRequestBBOX='1' srsname='EPSG:3857' typename='Public_OpenDataWFS:LIST_Cadastral_Parcels' url='https://services.thelist.tas.gov.au/arcgis/services/Public/OpenDataWFS/MapServer/WFSServer' version='2.0.0'

As mentioned previously this doesn't show any data
The WMS server connection works fine
https://services.thelist.tas.gov.au/arcgis/services/Basemaps/Orthophoto/MapServer/WmsServer
(Handy to add this base map first to get in the correct geo location)
Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong or if the app changes or server changes have caused the issue? I have sent a email to the server support to ask if they have changed anything that they are aware of.
I have also tried adding the ArcGIS REST server.
https://services.thelist.tas.gov.au/arcgis/rest
This loads and shows the (sub groups / servers?) but when I click on them I get Connection Failed : Error 403
As per the support document there is no username and password required for these connections
This is a link to the support document for GIS server connections
https://www.thelist.tas.gov.au/app/content/the-list/news_and_information/resources/list_spatial_web_services_user_guide.pdf
EDIT Installed 3.20.1 and tried my old file and that made no difference.
I tried changing the link to the WFS as suggested by @Mapperz to include the /rest/ but this doesn't connect to anything as I believe the directory is located in the ...arcgis/rest/.. but the link to the WFS doesn't include the /rest/
The WFS layers appear to be downloading data as sometimes I get a progress bar but still nothing displays

the word REST has been added to the url - so use https://services.thelist.tas.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/Public/OpenDataWFS/MapServer should fix your connection.

Its very confusing. I think the directory for all the information lies in ....arcgis/rest/services.... BUT the WFS server doesnt lie there. That gives me an error. When you click the WFS server link it is ......arcgis/services/.....

Something strange going on with the WFS CRS/coordinates. But if you connect as a REST service (note different URL) instead of WFS it displays fine: https://i.sstatic.net/YFAduSx7.png

Thanks @user2856 I had tried to add the REST server but hadn't drilled down to that level of the REST server. I had just added it at ....arcgis/rest/ not ...arcgis/rest/services/Public/OpenDataWFS/MapServer  So thank you, i can now access the data i need and have reported the problems with the WFS server to the operator
